# How to order the x axis based on the value matching a factor level with two facets in R ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, facet-wrap, facet-grid

I am making a stacked barplot of the proportion of time (Duration) spent on using three strategies (CA.presence: Presence, Possible presence, Absence) by  20 participants (participant) having performed two same tasks (task). I would like to facet by task.

I've used the following code and obtain this plot: [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHS3t.png)

```
CA_presence %>% ggplot(aes(fill=CA.presence, y= Duration, x= participant, label =    scales::percent(Duration))) + 
geom_bar(width = .7, position="fill", stat="identity") +
scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::label_percent()) +
facet_grid(~task) +
ggtitle("Presence of CA in the dataset") +
theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 15)) +
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 10)) +
theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size = 13)) +
labs(x = "Participant",
     y = "Proportion of discourse time",
     fill = "CA presence") +
theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 10)) +
theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 10)) +
scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Greens") +
coord_flip()
```

Here is the output of dput() for the head of the dataset:

```
structure(
  list(
    participant = c("L001", "L001", "L002", "L002", "L016", "L016"),
    task = c("T05", "T12", "T05", "T12", "T05", "T12"),
    language = c("French", "French", "French", "French", "French", "French"),
    Duration = c(8823, 46275, 2459, 38193, 20488, 160970),
    CA.presence = c("Presence", "Presence", "Presence", "Presence", "Presence", "Presence")
  ),
  class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"),
  row.names = c(NA, -6L), groups = structure(
    list(
      participant = c("L001", "L001", "L002", "L002", "L016", "L016"),
      task = c("T05", "T12", "T05", "T12", "T05", "T12"),
      .rows = structure(list(
        1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L
      ), ptype = integer(0), class = c(
        "vctrs_list_of",
        "vctrs_vctr", "list"
      ))
    ),
    class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"),
    row.names = c(NA, -6L), .drop = TRUE
  )
)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data best shared via `dput()`. Also, *order the x axis based on the value matching a factor level* is rather vague. Perhaps you could clarify how you want to order you x axis, whereas I guess you mean the y axis.

Comment: Thanks! Here's an example of what the dataset looks like: To clarify, I would like for participants to be ordered in an ascending order for the amount of time (Duration values) for the Presence level of the CA.presence column. This would make the plot nicer and easier to read, hopefully.

Comment: > head(CA_presence)
# A tibble: 6 × 5
# Groups:   participant, task [6]
  participant task  language Duration CA.presence
  <chr>       <chr> <chr>       <dbl> <chr>      
1 L001        T05   French       8823 Presence   
2 L001        T12   French      46275 Presence   
3 L002        T05   French       2459 Presence   
4 L002        T12   French      38193 Presence   
5 L016        T05   French      20488 Presence   
6 L016        T12   French     160970 Presence

Comment: Please share your data using `dput()`, e.g. run `dput(head(CA_presence))` and copy the output into your post (not as a comment).

Comment: Thank you for your patience, I've just added the output of dput().

Answer (score 0):

Ordering the bars in each facet individually requires some effort and a helper column. First, instead of relying on `position="fill"` compute the percentage shares manually. Second, arrange your dataset by `task`, by `CA.Presence` such that the `"Presence"` Category comes first (Note: I converted `CA.Presence` to a `factor` to make this easier) and finally by the (just created) share of duration column. Third, create a helper column as the interaction of `task` and `participant`. Fourth, convert to a `factor` with the order set according to the order in the (re-arranged) data for which I use `forcats::fct_inorder`. Fifth, map this new column on `y` (or `x` if your prefer using `coord_flip`). Finally, get rid of the task part in the axis labels:

In general, you could use `reorder` to create a `factor` ordered by the value of a numeric variable. Your case is a bit special as you want to reorder by one category of a stacked barchart (and one category of the faceting variable??). To this end we could use a small trick, which means to use an `ifelse` to set the values for the other categories to zero for the reordering and use `FUN=sum`. Using this trick I `reorder`ed `participant`s according to the value for `"Presence"` category for task `"TO5"`.

As your example data contained only of the `CA.presence` categories I  created some fake example data:

```r
set.seed(123)

CA_presence <- expand.grid(
  participant = c("L001", "L002", "L016", "L004", "L005"),
  task = c("T05", "T12"),
  CA.presence = c("Presence", "Possible presence", "Absence")
) |>
  transform(
    Duration = rnorm(30, 20000, 5000)
  )

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn=FALSE)

CA_presence <- CA_presence |>
  mutate(
    CA.presence = factor(
      CA.presence, rev(c("Presence", "Possible presence", "Absence"))
    )
  ) |> 
  mutate(
    duration_share = Duration / sum(Duration), 
    .by = c(task, participant)
  ) |> 
  # Order by Task, Presence first and Duration ascending
  arrange(task, desc(CA.presence), desc(duration_share)) |> 
  # Create a helper column to be mapped on y
  mutate(
    group = paste(task, participant, sep = "."),
    group = forcats::fct_inorder(group)
  )

CA_presence |>
  ggplot(aes(
    fill = CA.presence,
    x = duration_share,
    y = group,
    label = scales::percent(duration_share)
  )) +
  geom_col(
    width = .7, position = "fill"
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::label_percent()) +
  # Remove the task part from the labels
  scale_y_discrete(labels = \(x) gsub("^.*?\\.", "", x)) +
  facet_wrap(~task, scales = "free_y") +
  labs(
    x = "Proportion of discourse time",
    y = "Participant",
    fill = "CA presence",
    title = "Presence of CA in the dataset"
  ) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 10)) +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 10)) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 15, hjust = 0.5)) +
  theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 10)) +
  theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size = 13)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Greens")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks and apologies if I wasn't very clear. I am not trying to reorder participants by only the values only in T05. I would like to plot the distribution of the 3 types of CA presence as done here.  I'd like for participants to be ordered (separately in each facet) by how much they resort to Presence (as estimated by the time they spent on using it). In my plot, Presence is in dark green and I would like to have participants in ascending order, so that there is more dark green the further down you go in each facet. I think scales_free will probably be needed in facet_grid. Thanks!

Comment: Now I got it. See my edit. Requires some effort and I switched to facet_wrap to have a y scale for both panels.